# MobileVLCKit-prod shows black screen (Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, mobile, vlc, xcode9

When compiling MobileVLCKit-prod (version 2.7.9) and Xcode 9 the player plays sound but doesn't plays the video.

I think is SDK or Xcode related since I already have my app in the AppStore and it works perfectly with MobileVLCKit-prod (version 2.7.9) but it was compiled with Xcode 8.

If I try to compile with MobileVLCKit-unstable (version 3.0.0a42) it works with Xcode 9.

Anyway I feel the MobileVLCKit-unstable version is too much "unstable" compared to MobileVLCKit-prod (version 2.7.9).
Someone experienced a way to use MobileVLCKit-prod (version 2.7.9) with Xcode 9?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a working version? I am trying to do that also but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when version 3 came out.